# Let $A \subseteq B$ and assume $B$ is of measure zero e.g $m(B)=0$. Show that $m(A)=0.$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Let $A \subseteq B$ and assume $B$ is of measure zero e.g $m(B)=0$. Show that $m(A)=0.$

Using Caratheodory’s criterion we have since $B$ is measurable $$m(A)=m(A \cap B)+m(A \setminus B).$$

Since $A \subset B \implies A \cap B = B$ and $A \setminus B= \emptyset$ so $$m(A) \le m(B)+ m(\emptyset)=0+0=0$$

And since $m(A) \ge 0$ it must be that $m(A)=0$ and so $A$ is measurable?

Comment: Your solution has a mistake: $A\subset B$ does not imply $A\cap B=B$.

Comment: I see. It is however true that since $A \subset B \implies m(A \cap B) \le m(B)$ and the result holds?